# Understanding string diagram page 115 Humphreys Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, roots

Trying to understand the figure on page 115 of Humphreys 'Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory'.

He takes $V(\lambda)$ as a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$. Where $\lambda = 4\lambda_1+3\lambda_2$, where these are the first two fundamental weights, $\lambda_1=\frac13(2\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$ and $\lambda_2=\frac13 (\alpha_1+2\alpha_2)$, where $\alpha_i$ are the two simple roots of $A_2$.

He starts the diagram from the top right I imagine, and applies lowering operations until he obtains the whole diagram. But he seems to have way more weight spaces than he should?

[image: String diagram]

Comment: The dimension of $V(\lambda)$ is 90, as given by the [Weyl dimension formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula), for example. I count 90 dimensions worth of weight spaces on that diagram.

Comment: @Joppy Okay, that part I can now understand. I see that I have 21 nodes with dimension $1$ on the outer most layer, and then moving inwards I have $15$ of dimension $2$, $9$ of dimension $3$ and $3$ of dimension $4$. Giving me $90$ dimensions. I'll have to think more on the geometric meaning of this diagram though.